# Specify lifetime for AppDomain in Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, scope, windows-services, appdomain

I have a long-running Windows service that creates two app domains. Based on the behavior of the application it looks like the app domains are being discarded earlier than I would like. Ideally I would like the app domains to also be long running (basically never get cleaned up unless the Windows service shuts down). Is there a way to do this?

I create the app domains using a factory method called twice (it creates two different types of objects, each within its own app domain), which includes this code (switch statement removed for simplicity)...

```
AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(someVariable.ToString());
return (MyObject) appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                        typeof (MyObject).Assembly.FullName,
                        typeof (MyObject).FullName,
                        false,
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                        null,
                        new object[] {id},
                        null,
                        null);
```

... where `MyObject` inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`.

Comment: Maybe I'm worng, but app domain will not be self-destructed never, if it's being discarded then your app must be doing it, are you holding a reference to the app domain? maybe if no code is being executed on the domain and you don't have a reference to it maybe it's being collected by GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the AppDomain, it's the [remoting lease time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300474.aspx) for MyObject.

You can increase the lease time with the [`LifetimeServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.lifetime.lifetimeservices(v=vs.110).aspx) class (LeaseTime property). For a more exhaustive example, see `Figure 4 Providing New Lease Properties for an Object` in the linked article:

```
public class MyObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
        ILease lease = (ILease)base.InitializeLifetimeService();
        Debug.Assert(lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial);

        //Set lease properties 
        lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); 
        lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10); 
        lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2); 
        return lease;
    }
}
```

Anyway, I would set the lease time to something very large because I suspect you don't want to manually prolong the lease time periodically (on renewal time). However, this also depends on what actually MyObject does in the other AppDomain. If it's holding some resources or anything that doesn't work out on the long term, maybe it's better to just let it be disposed and re-activate it when needed.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need to call InitializeLifetimeService() explicitly after creating the object, or will it automatically be called as part of the creation of it (since it inherits from MarhsalByRefObject)?

Comment: @mayabelle: I actually never used it like this, but by the looks of it, it will be called automatically. When I needed this, I have set the lease time globally, via the `LifetimeServices` class.

Comment: Do you mean just like this: `LifetimeServices.LeaseTime = TimeSpan.MaxValue;` and it will apply to all app domains? And if so where do I put that? Just when the Windows service starts?

Comment: @mayabelle: Yes, like that. You need to call that anywhere before you activate any instance, so when the service starts is just fine.

Comment: @mayabelle: Not really, because you already have a very large lifetime. If you set the lifetime to a lower value, like 1 hour, and you are certain theat you call that object at least once per hour then it would make sense to set the renewal time to 1 hour as well. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: I figured that out right after posting, that's why I deleted the comment... sorry. Thanks for your help!